# Pandas: Add a row at the top with day based on date in the column headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a DataFrame pivot table with dates as column headers as can be seen below:

```
Due Date    2020-01-1   2020-04-12  2020-04-22  2020-05-06  2020-05-1
Customer                                            
Aviva          0            0           0           0         1000  
Debenhams      0        75325           0           0           0   
H&M         1204            0           0           0           0
```

I would like to add a row below the headers which has the day of the week corresponding to the date of the header:

```
    Due Date    2020-01-1   2020-04-12  2020-04-22  2020-05-06  2020-05-1
    Day         Wednesday     Sunday    Wednesday    Wednesday    Friday
    Customer                                            
    Aviva          0            0           0           0         1000  
    Debenhams      0        75325           0           0           0   
    H&M         1204            0           0           0           0
```

I get that i have to call the day_name() method on the datetime headers which I can do and I tried to iterate over the columns and find a way to do it that way but with no luck.

Also if its not possible to get it exactly that way, then any other ideas are welcome.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create MultiIndex by second level created by [`DatetimeIndex.day_name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.day_name.html):

```
df.columns = [df.columns, pd.to_datetime(df.columns).day_name()]

print (df)
          2020-01-1 2020-04-12 2020-04-22 2020-05-06 2020-05-1
          Wednesday     Sunday  Wednesday  Wednesday    Friday
Due Date                                                      
Aviva             0          0          0          0      1000
Debenhams         0      75325          0          0         0
H&M            1204          0          0          0         0
```

If want also set columns names use [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html):

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns, 
                                        pd.to_datetime(df.columns).day_name()], 
                                        names=('Date','Day'))

print (df)
Date      2020-01-1 2020-04-12 2020-04-22 2020-05-06 2020-05-1
Day       Wednesday     Sunday  Wednesday  Wednesday    Friday
Due Date                                                      
Aviva             0          0          0          0      1000
Debenhams         0      75325          0          0         0
H&M            1204          0          0          0         0
```

EDIT:

If possible some non datetime values in columns:

```
df['sum'] = df.sum(axis=1)
df.columns = [df.columns, pd.to_datetime(df.columns, errors='coerce').day_name().fillna('-')]

print (df)
          2020-01-1 2020-04-12 2020-04-22 2020-05-06 2020-05-1    sum
          Wednesday     Sunday  Wednesday  Wednesday    Friday      -
Due Date                                                             
Aviva             0          0          0          0      1000   1000
Debenhams         0      75325          0          0         0  75325
H&M            1204          0          0          0         0   1204
```

Comment: Ah thats great thank you, but what if i have a totals column at the end which isn't a datetime so it cannot be parsed, how can I ignore it from being parsed? Sorry forgot to add it in the question